# Grails package bypassing certificate

Tags: grails, certificate

I would like to ignore certificate when building my project. I am trying to do somenthing like that.

```
grails -Dgrails.env=production -Dserver.ssl.enabled=false package --stacktrace
```

And I receive the message below. **Could anyone help me to ignore certificate while building process is running?**

Unzipping /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.5-bin/daoimhu7k5rlo48ntmxw2ok3e/gradle-3.5-bin.zip to /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.5-bin/daoimhu7k5rlo48ntmxw2ok3e

3700Set executable permissions for: /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.5-bin/daoimhu7k5rlo48ntmxw2ok3e/gradle-3.5/bin/gradle

3701FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

3702* What went wrong:

3703A problem occurred configuring root project 'cmberp'.

3704> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.

3705 > Could not resolve org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:3.3.11.

3706 Required by:

3707 project :

3708 > Could not resolve org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:3.3.11.

3709 > Could not get resource 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-gradle-plugin/3.3.11/grails-gradle-plugin-3.3.11.pom'.

3710 > Could not GET 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-gradle-plugin/3.3.11/grails-gradle-plugin-3.3.11.pom'.

3711 > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

3712 > Could not resolve org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.1.12.

3713 Required by:

3714 project :

3715 > Could not resolve org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.1.12.

3716 > Could not get resource 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/hibernate5/6.1.12/hibernate5-6.1.12.pom'.

3717 > Could not GET 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/hibernate5/6.1.12/hibernate5-6.1.12.pom'.

3718 > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

3719 > Could not resolve org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.2.9.

3720 Required by:

3721 project :

3722 > Could not resolve org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.2.9.

3723 > Could not get resource 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/views-gradle/1.2.9/views-gradle-1.2.9.pom'.

3724 > Could not GET 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/views-gradle/1.2.9/views-gradle-1.2.9.pom'.

3725 > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

3726 > Could not resolve io.github.robwin:jgitflow-gradle-plugin:0.6.0.

3727 Required by:

3728 project :

3729 > Could not resolve io.github.robwin:jgitflow-gradle-plugin:0.6.0.

3730 > Could not get resource 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/io/github/robwin/jgitflow-gradle-plugin/0.6.0/jgitflow-gradle-plugin-0.6.0.pom'.

3731 > Could not GET 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/io/github/robwin/jgitflow-gradle-plugin/0.6.0/jgitflow-gradle-plugin-0.6.0.pom'.

3732 > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Why ignore the certificate, instead of trusting it?  Alternatively, you can reference http://repo.grails.org to connect insecurely, if you're OK with that.  (It would be better to trust the certificate.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a network problem and it is already resolved.